# zsh command expansion applies esacping

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, escape-characters

I have a string `S`, for which I want to replace every `b` character with `\\` (two forward slashes).
So this is what I have:

```bash
$ S="abc"
$ A=$(echo $S | sed 's/b/\\\\/')
```

In bash I get the expected output:

```bash
$ echo $A
a\\c
```

but in zsh I have

```bash
$ echo $A
a\c
```

It seems to me that zsh's behavior is unexpected, why does it behave this way?

I want `A` to contain two forward slashes (so I can use it later as a regex, for example). How can I achieve this in a cross-shell way?

Comment: it does contain two *back*-slashes, you're just printing it with `echo` which in zsh treats backslashes specially. Try `echo 'foo\nbar'` in Bash and in zsh, and then do the same with `echo -e` and `echo -E`.

Comment: See also the `xpg_echo` option in bash to make its `echo` UNIX compliant in that regard, and the `bsdecho` option in `zsh` to make it non-compliant.

Comment: OTOH in both Bash and zsh you could use `A="${S/b/\\\\}"` instead of calling out to `sed`, see e.g.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion